# Função explode que ignora conteúdo dentro de aspas

Tags: php, explode

Estou trabalhando num projeto em `PHP` que precisa fazer `import` de arquivo `CSV`, cujo separador é por `;`. Estou usando `explode` para fazer o processo, mas o problema é que em alguns casos o conteúdo pode vir com `;` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
principio_ativo              | descricao                              
CIANOCOBALAMINA; DICLOFENACO | 50 MG + 50 MG COM REV CT BL AL PVDC INC
```

o arquivo gerado fica da seguinte maneira:

```
principio_ativo;descricao
"CIANOCOBALAMINA; DICLOFENACO";50 MG + 50 MG COM REV CT BL AL PVDC INC

 $lines = file($destinationPath.'/'.$result['file']);
 for($i=1; $i<count($lines); $i++){
     $line = $lines[$i];
     $explode = explode(',', $line);
     list($principioAtivo, $apresentacao) = $explode;
 }

//saída:
Array
(
    [0] => "CIANOCOBALAMINA
    [1] =>  DICLOFENACO"
    [2] => 50 MG + 50 MG COM REV CT BL AL PVDC INC
)

//saída ideal:
Array
(
    [0] => "CIANOCOBALAMINA; DICLOFENACO"
    [1] => 50 MG + 50 MG COM REV CT BL AL PVDC INC
)
```

Ao utilizar a função `explode` precisava que o conteúdo que estivesse entre `"` fosse ignorado pelo `explode` há alguma maneira de solucionar isso?

[Neste link](https://repl.it/repls/DarkSelfassuredJava) fiz um exemplo do que ocorre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, utilizar as ferramentas certas para o trabalho. Se está processando um arquivo CSV, utilize a função [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php) para ler o conteúdo. Tal função possui um parâmetro que você define encapsulador de *string*:

```
fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] ) : array
```

Ou seja, basta fazer:

```
$stream = fopen("arquivo.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($stream, 0, ";", '"')) !== false) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

E assim ter o retorno:

```
Array
(
    [0] => principio_ativo
    [1] => descricao
)
Array
(
    [0] => CIANOCOBALAMINA; DICLOFENACO
    [1] => 50 MG + 50 MG COM REV CT BL AL PVDC INC
)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou direitinho!